# 'System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000012' error when calling c# dll

Tags: python, c#, clr

I am trying to decompress gzip by calling a c# dll from python.

When I run c# code in vscode, there is no problem,
An error occurs when called from Python.

What should I do to fix this error?

Part of calling C# dll from Python:

```
import clr 
file = 'path/to/MyLibrary.dll'
clr.AddReference(os.path.abspath(file))
from MyLibrary import DepressGZ
obj = DepressGZ()
result = obj.depress_gz(str)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    result = obj.depress_gz(str)
System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000012 from typeref (expected class 'System.IO.MemoryStream' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <36bc7f04913b4c0da9c2e431738df79b>:0
```

I'm using a MacBook(monterey), and the source will run on Ubuntu as well.

When I searched for it, it also appeared related to xamarin.form. What is this?
If I need to modify anything related to xamarin.form, please let me know in detail.

thanks.